# Golang logger fatal

Tags: logging, go

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

func main() {   
        // Log into byte
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        logInfo := log.New(&buf, "[Info] ", log.Lshortfile)
        logInfo.Print("Hello, log file!")
        logInfo.Printf("Hello, %s", "crazy")
        fmt.Print(&buf)
        logInfo.Fatalln("Ut oh")
        fmt.Print(&buf)
   }
```

Hello. I am trying to use log.Fatal or log.Fatalln instead of having log.New and os.Exit. However, it seems like the logger does not log "Ut oh" part (logInfo.Fatalln)

Following is expected output:

```
[Info] main.go:17: Hello, log file!
[Info] main.go:18: Hello, crazy
[Info] main.go:17: Hello, log file!
[Info] main.go:18: Hello, crazy
[Info] main.go:xx: Ut oh
```

Following is what I got:

```
[Info] main.go:17: Hello, log file!
[Info] main.go:18: Hello, crazy

it seems like it didn't do anything from logInfo.Fatalln("Ut oh")
```

Could you please tell me what I missed?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`log.Fatalln` exits your app, so the second `fmt.Print(&buf)` does not get executed.

Change your logger to write to `os.Stderr` or something and you will see `Ut oh` print.